# Import a list into python sql db

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to import a list into an sql db using python.
I have searched the internet for answers, but am finding solutions that do not work for my program.

```
def create_table(db_name,sql):
with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_name = "TVshows.db"
    sql = """create table TVPrograms
    (ShowID integer,
    Showname text,
    Primary Key(ShowID))"""


def insert_data(TVshows):
    with sqlite3.connect("TVshows.db") as db:
        cursor=db.cursor()
        count=0
        while count <5:
            ShowID=TVshows[0]
            cursor.execute("INSERT into TVprograms(Showname,ShowID) VALUES (?,?);',[','.join(TVshows)])")
            count=count+1
            ShowID=TVshows[0+1]
            db.commit()       
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()

TVshows = ['The X Files', 'Breaking Bad', "Star Trek", "Daredevil"]`

insert_data(TVshows)
```

It errors up on me. I can't figure out how to get this to work.
My error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "H:/Python/tvshow.py", line 32, in <module> insert_data(TVshows) 

File "H:/Python/tvshow.py", line 23, in insert_data cursor.execute("INSERT into TVprograms(Showname,ShowID) VALUES (?,?);',[','.join(TVshows)])")

sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

Comment: Include in your question the error you receive.

Comment: My error message:                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python/tvshow.py", line 32, in <module>
    insert_data(TVshows)
  File "H:/Python/tvshow.py", line 23, in insert_data
    cursor.execute("INSERT into TVprograms(Showname,ShowID) VALUES (?,?);',[','.join(TVshows)])")
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.

Comment: @Chris To edit the question, click "edit".